# How to display comparisons with set expression?

Tags: qlikview

My dataset has WeekEndingDate and Sales. I am displaying a straight table with all the selected data but I need to have another table showing the following:

```
                 Sales  (other columns...)

First week  :    1,000

Last week   :    1,350

Difference  :      350

Difference %:      35%
```

My questions:

a) Can I have the above in one chart/table, or I need 4 different charts showing columns filtered by set expressions?

b) My strategy is having 2 variables (vMinWeek and vMaxWeek), and using them in set expressions. Is that the best route?

c) My set expressions (below) are not working - they sum the whole data set. Would you please help me understanding why?

```
=max ({$<WeekEndingDate={'$(vMinWeek)'}>}  Sales)
```

Thank you for your help!

Mara

Comment: If you want to create the exact chart you display above, you should be able to. I have something similar in a Pivot chart on one of my dashboards. I'm not 100% sure why your set expression(s) aren't working.  Are vMinWeek and vMaxWeek hard coded date values? I would have a pivot chart with no dimensions and four expressions. One for each of: First Week, Last Week, Difference and Difference %. Once I have the expressions set for them, in the chart object itself, click and drag the fields from where they are as columns down to the row, you'll see a blue arrow indicator pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason your set isn't working is that your WeekEnd date is formatted as a date and your variable is formatted as a number.

The trick with Set Analysis is always to think what you would have to type in a list box to get to your answer. So even though QlikView stores WeekEnd 2014/08/18 as 41869 you can't type 41869 in the WeekEnd list box and get back that date. So I would make your variables of the form `=date(min(WeekEnd))`.

The second part of your question; getting the table you want. I would do like this. I make a loose table with the dimension values, dual is so that it sorts correctly in the chart we are going to build.

```
load dual(D,N) as DIM inline [
D,N
First Week,1
Last Week,2
Difference,3
Dif %,4
];
```

I like defining my variables in the script as well, so I would do this.

```
set vFirstWeek='=date(min(WeekEnd))';
set vLastWeek='=date(max(WeekEnd))';`
```

Then when building the straight table we use the dimension as DIM but because DIM isn't connected to anything we have to do some work to get it to display values that fit those dimension values. The `num(,'# ##0')` is just to format the % differently from the sums. For this to work the number format in the Number tab of the chart must be set to Expression Default.

```
if(DIM='First Week',num(sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vFirstWeek)'}>} Sales),'# ##0'),
    if(DIM='Last Week',num(sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vLastWeek)'}>} Sales),'# ##0'),
        if(DIM='Difference',num(sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vFirstWeek)'}>} Sales)-sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vLastWeek)'}>} Sales),'# ##0'),
            if(DIM='Dif %',num((sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vFirstWeek)'}>} Sales)-sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vLastWeek)'}>} Sales))/sum({<WeekEnd={'$(vLastWeek)'}>} Sales),'0.00%')))))
```